# How to access logcat output from flutter integration tests programmatically?

Tags: flutter, adb, integration-testing, logcat

I want to automatically test a flutter app which uses a platform plugin and need to access the adb logcat output programmatically.

Is there a way to parse the log output from dart and check if some text was printed, e.g. after a button was pressed?

I am using Android studio to develop my app.

Comment: any luck with this? did you find a solution finally?

Comment: no, not yet but I didn't search any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Dart's `print()` outputs the system console, you can also use the command `flutter logs`.
according to flutter website [flutter offical docs](https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs) :

"The Dart print() function outputs to the system console, which you can view using flutter logs (which is basically a wrapper around adb logcat)."

Comment: Yes I know how to read the console manually (adb logcat, flutter log, ...), but the problem is I want to read the console from code to check programatically if a specific output was printed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin called [logcat_monitor](https://pub.dev/packages/logcat_monitor) on pub.dev.

Its biggest advantage over the other logcat plugin is that it allows continuous monitoring of logcat messages.

## how to use

Add the dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  logcat_monitor: ^0.0.4
```

1. Create a function to consume the *logcat* messages

```dart
  void _mylistenStream(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) {
      _logBuffer.writeln(value);
    }
  }
```

2. Register your function as a listener to get logs then use it in anyway within your app.

```dart
    LogcatMonitor.addListen(_mylistenStream);
```

3. Start the logcat monitor passing the filter parameters as defined in *logcat* tool.

```dart
    await LogcatMonitor.startMonitor("*.*");
```